# How can I show all files via filedialog.askdirectory?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple image file renumbering program.
When I present the user with this:

```
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

it works as expected, but I need it to show all the files in the
directory.

I realise this is not standard dialog practice to show files when a folder is required, but I was hoping a wildcard like this:

```
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory(*.*)
```

would work, but no such luck.

I have tried filetypes tuple as used in select a file dialog, which does show files, though I got a bit lost  and got errors all the time.
I'm still a total beginner

If this is not possible then I suppose I'll have to present the user with a listing of the files in the folder before they are operated on.

regards
Steve

Comment: As far as I can see, Tkinter `askdirectory()` wraps the `Tk` function `tk_chooseDirectory` and this function does not take that option. See [Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.htm)

Comment: Use `askopenfilename()`, with a prompt like "Choose any file in the folder to be processed", then use `os.path.dirname()` to discard the filename from the path.

Comment: OK thanks guys, @jasonharper 's  idea is a bit of a hack, but will do me, thank you.