# Show files inside folder when using Python Tkinter tkFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I use tkinter's `filedialog` to call a pop-up to select a folder.
It also works as it should! However, when I select a directory, the files in it are not displayed.
(I think this is because you can only select directories and not files?!)

For completion:

```
folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select Folder:")  # open folder dialog
```

[LEFT: folderdialog RIGHT: inside of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbo92.png)

Is there a way to still display the included files (maybe as disabled)? It would be a helpful visual response if I selected the folder I wanted to open. I have not found anything in the documentation of `tkinter.askdirectory`.

Comment: Use `filedialog.askopenfilename` instead. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#native-load-save-dialogs) for some of the options.

Comment: The problem is that then i can also choose a file and i want a user only be able to choose directories but see the content of the folder. 
Is it possible to set the filetype to directories?

Comment: I can't see any option for it. The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51192795/7519434) may be useful.

Comment: Ah nice, Thanks! I will check it out :)